# Understanding SoftEther VPN packet log

Tags: vpn, log-files, packet, softether

Help me to identify each part of a packet log from softether VPN.

for example, the below given is a packet log.

```
2017-06-07,23:40:20.888,SID-USER-[L2TP]-15,SID-SECURENAT-1,CA9DC6D826F0,00AC3A3F04D0,0x0800,78,TCP_CONNECTv4,SYN,192.168.52.112,56618,17.252.156.12,https(443),2147151822,0,WindowSize=65535,-,61.5.234.68,-
```

I can Identify date, time, userid from the above, but I would like to know about all parts in that log.

I could not find an official documentation that explains packet log format in [SoftEther website](https://www.softether.org/Special:Search?search=log%20format).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found it after checking SoftEther source code.

Here is what I found (packet log format for a TCP packet):

```
<Date>,<Time>,<Source session>,<Destination session>,
<Source MAC address>,<Destination MAC address>,<MAC protocol>,
<Packet size>,<Type of packet>,<TCP Flags(Control Bits)>,
<Source IP address>,<Source port>,<Destination IP address>,
<Destination Port>,<TCP Sequence Number>,<TCP ACK Number>,
<TCP window size and Meta Info>,<Packet Data>,
<Physical IP address(Source)>,< Physical IP address(Destination)>
```

*Source : https://github.com/SoftEtherVPN/SoftEtherVPN*

*File: SoftEtherVPN/src/Cedar/Logging.c*